# What are the overheads of using AUTOINCREMENT for SQLite on Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, auto-increment

In the SQLite Documentation, it includes the following :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

and

> The behavior implemented by the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is subtly
>   different from the default behavior. With AUTOINCREMENT, rows with
>   automatically selected ROWIDs are guaranteed to have ROWIDs that have
>   never been used before by the same table in the same database. And the
>   automatically generated ROWIDs are guaranteed to be monotonically
>   increasing. These are important properties in certain applications.
>   But if your application does not need these properties, you should
>   probably stay with the default behavior since the use of AUTOINCREMENT
>   requires additional work to be done as each row is inserted and thus
>   causes INSERTs to run a little slower.

The above quotes are from [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

So what sort of impact is to be expected and by how much is AUTOINCREMENT a little slower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My estimate, noting that I'm not a statistician, is that the overhead is something like  **8-12%** slower.

I obtained the results using **3** structurally similar and simple **tables** with two TEXT columns, running **10,000** inserts per each table, repeating this 5 times on 4 devices.

**Table 1 (Dflt column)** was created with just the two TEXT Columns (thus utilising the default ROWID).

**Table 2 (AI column)** was created using `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` in addition to the two TEXT columns.

**Table 3 (No AI column)** was created using `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` in addition to the two TEXT columns.

So **Table 2** uses the  *slightly different ROWID selection algorithm* for inserts.

The four devices used were :-

- (1) A Genymotion emulated device (Custom Tablet - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 1536x2048
  )
- (2) An Onix 10" tablet (AT101-1116
  )
- (3) An HTC 1 M8 (HTC_0PKV1
  )
- (4) A Lenevo A10-30 tablet (Lenovo TB2-X30F
  )

  The results I obtained were :-

[image]

The results are more favourable when everything is run in just 1 transaction (i.e `beginTransaction();` before any inserts, with `setTransactionSuccessful();` and `endTransaction();` after all inserts (for all tables i.e. the entire 150,000 inserts), e.g. :-

[image]

*Comparison of the two tables, highlights the benefits that using transactions can have upon performance.*