# How do FK:PK relations work in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I am using the DB Browser for SQLite to try and figure this out. I've opened Northwind.sqlite and in it it shows me the following for a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order Details` (
    `OrderID`   int,
    `ProductID` int,
    `UnitPrice` float ( 26 ),
    `Quantity`  int,
    `Discount`  float ( 13 ),
    PRIMARY KEY(`OrderID`,`ProductID`)
);
```

However, in the Sql Server Northwind OrderID and ProductID are foreign keys, not primary keys. Does this work differently in SQLite? And if so, how do the relationships work?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above will create a table that has no FOREIGN keys but 2 indexes.

- One a largely hidden index according to **rowid**.
- The other, `PRIMARY KEY(`OrderID`,`ProductID`)` will be an index according to the combination of **OrderId** and **ProductID**.

**some things about rowid** (aka id)

- **rowid** is an automatically created column called **rowid** (it can also be referenced using **oid** or ***rowid*** (case independent)) and if present is really the primary key.
- **rowid** will be a unique signed integer using up to 64 bits. The lowest value and also the first value will be **1**, the highest value being **9223372036854775807**.
- In later versions of SQLite 3.8.2 on the WITHOUT ROWID keyword was added to allow suppression of the **rowid** column/index (your Order Details table may benefit being a without rowid table).
- if a column is defined with the type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` then that column (there can only be 1 such column per table) is an alias of for the **rowid** column.

  - AUTOINCREMENT introduces a rule that when inserting a row the rowid must be greater than any that exist or existed.
  - It DOES NOT guarantee that the **rowid** will monotonically increase, although generally the id will (even without AUTOINCREMENT (perhaps the most misused/misunderstood keyword in SQLite)).
  - Without AUTOINCREMENT SQlite may find a lower **rowid** and use that, but not until a **rowid** of **9223372036854775807** has been reached.
  - AUTOINCREMENT, if a **rowid** of **9223372036854775807** has been reached will is an SQLITE_FULL exception.
  - AUTOINCREMENT results in overheads (e.q. a table named sqlite_sequence is then maintained recording the highest given sequence number). The documentation recommends that it not be used unless required, which is rarely the case.
  - Some limited testing I did resulted in an 8-12% greater processing time for AUTOINCREMENT. [What are the overheads of using AUTOINCREMENT for SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384919/what-are-the-overheads-of-using-autoincrement-for-sqlite-on-android)
  - For more about **rowid** see [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and also [Clustered Indexes and the WITHOUT ROWID Optimization](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)

Coding PRIMARY KEY (if not on an INTEGER column i.e. not an alias of **rowid**) implies a UNIQUE constraint. It is not saying/checking that the value or any of the values in a clustered index exists in any other table.

- Note null is not considered to be the same value, so in your `Order Details` table it is possible to have any combination of the values as null.

Coding a `FOREIGN KEY` introduces a constraint that the referenced value(s) must exist in the respective table/column. Additionally :-

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key
>   of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent
>   key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or
>   have a UNIQUE index. If the parent key columns have a UNIQUE index,
>   then that index must use the collation sequences that are specified in
>   the CREATE TABLE statement for the parent table.
>   [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Considering all of this you may want to do make some changes to the `Order Details` table :-

- You could make it a WITHOUT ROWID table.
- You could make both the `OrderID` and the `ProductID` columns NOT NULL.
- You could add FOREIGN KEY's to both the `OrderID` and the `ProductID` columns.

So perhaps you could have :-

```
CREATE TABLE `Order Details` (
    `OrderID`   int NOT NULL REFERENCES `Orders` (`OrderId`), -- ADDED NOT NULL and FKEY
    `ProductID` int NOT NULL REFERENCES `Products`(`ProductId`) , -- ADDED NOT NULL and FKEY
    `UnitPrice` float ( 26 ),
    `Quantity`  int,
    `Discount`  float ( 13 ),
    PRIMARY KEY(`OrderID`,`ProductID`)
    )
    WITHOUT ROWID -- ADDED WITHOUT ROWID
;
```

- The above uses column constraints

Alternately, utilising TABLE constraints, you could do :-

```
CREATE TABLE `Order Details` (
    `OrderID`   int NOT NULL, -- ADDED NOT NULL
    `ProductID` int NOT NULL, -- ADDED NOT NULL
    `UnitPrice` float ( 26 ),
    `Quantity`  int,
    `Discount`  float ( 13 ),
    PRIMARY KEY(`OrderID`,`ProductID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`OrderId`) REFERENCES `Orders`(`OrderId`), -- ADDED FKEY AS TABLE CONSTRAINT
    FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `Products`(`ProductID`) -- ADDED FKEY AS TABLE CONSTRAINT
    )
    WITHOUT ROWID -- ADDED WITHOUT ROWID
;
```

Both have the same outcome, the only difference being where the FOREIGN KEY constraints are defined.

Both the above assumes that the referenced tables are `Orders` and `Products`.

Comment: First off thank you. This is super helpful. Second, the Northwind.sqlite comes from the SQLite site - any idea why they didn't put in the PK:FK relationships? thanks - dave

Comment: A quick look and found [Northwind.Sqlite3.create.sql](https://github.com/jpwhite3/northwind-SQLite3/blob/master/Northwind.Sqlite3.create.sql) which does have FK's e.g. `FOREIGN KEY ([OrderID]) REFERENCES [Orders] ([OrderID]) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 FOREIGN KEY ([ProductID]) REFERENCES [Products] ([ProductID]) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION` and also **-- Modified by Len Boyette @ 2013-02-08
-- Added foreign keys**

Comment: Important note for others needing this, the sql scripts referenced above have the FK:PK relationships. But the various Northwind.sqlite files at both northwind-SQLite3 and another at the official SQLite site do NOT have the FK:PK relationships