# SQLITE: Best practices about using AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: performance, sqlite, rowid

According to the [official manual](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

***"The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed."***

So it is better not to use it? Do you have any benchmark of using the implicit rowid against using AUTOINCREMENT?

Comment: Only if you use SQLite on a really weak embedded device, writing to slow storage like an SD card

Comment: It's better not to use it, unless you really need its special behavior, which a good database design shouldn't imo. The keyword is badly named and one of the most commonly misunderstood parts of sqlite thanks to that.

Comment: @Shawn Why badly named? It does not increment the last value by one?Could you elaborate?

Comment: @joan The documentation explains all. An INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or unaliased rowid increments already if a value isn't explicitly given in an INSERT; AUTOINCREMENT controls what happens after the highest possible rowid is used and another one is needed. That number is so incredibly huge you'll never encounter it unless manually setting rowids near it, meaning AUTOINCREMENT is needless overhead. (And I think a good database design shouldn't care if rowids get reused)

Comment: At this point, @Shawn has given you (IMO) excellent advice, and backed it up with references.  So now, you *should* be asking yourself, why you're asking random people on SO to second-guess the very clear guidelines in the official documentation of SQLite3 itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended in the documentation, it is better to not use AUTOINCREMENT unless you need to ensure that the alias of the **rowid** (aka the id) is greater then any that have been added. However, (in normal use) it's a moot point as such, as even without AUTOINCREMENT, until you have reached 9223372036854775807 rows then a higher rowid/id will result.

If you do reach the id/rowid of 9223372036854775807, then that's it if you have AUTOINCREMENT coded, as an SQLITE_FULL exception will happen. Whilst without AUTOINCREMENT attempts will be made to get an unused id/rowid.

AUTOINCREMENT adds a row (table if required) to sqlite_sequence that records the highest allocated id. The difference between with and without AUTOINCREMENT is that the sqlite_sequecence table is referenced, whilst without AUTOINCREMENT the isn't. So if a row is deleted that has the highest id AUTOINCREMENT gets the highest ever allocated id from the sqlite_sequence table (and user the greater of that or `max(rowid)`), without doesn't so it uses the highest in the table where the row is being inserted (equivalent to `max(rowid)`).

With limited testing an overhead of 8-12% was found to be the overhead as per [What are the overheads of using AUTOINCREMENT for SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384919/what-are-the-overheads-of-using-autoincrement-for-sqlite-on-android)
.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried sqlite3 autoincrement with python3 and sqlalchemy 1.4.

Before enable autoincrement on Integer Primary Key ID column, single insert use about less than 0.1 seconds. After enable this feature, single insert use more than 1.5 seconds.

The performance gap is big.