# SQLite or text files faster for storing sensor data in Android?

Tags: android, csv, android-sqlite, text-files

I would like to implement an app which stores data from several sensors such as acceleration, gyroscope, ambient light and touch (pressure, position). There are two possibilities for saving the data. I could either use the SQLite database provided by Android or plain CSV files. My main concern is the performance because the sampling rate of the sensors is pretty high.

Is the performance higher for the built-in SQLite database or for CSV files? Or are there other possibilities which provide better performance? For the database, I could use one database for each stream or only one single database for all the streams and for the CSV files I would use one file for each stream.

Comment: This library is really good and efficient: https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/

Comment: Probably for small amount of data CSV is gonna be faster, however as data grows SQLite will perform better. I would definitely go with a database.

Comment: @m0skit0 I think the sensor data will be sampled with for example 20 hz each, so data will grow fast but every entry is only one number. If I would use a database, what transaction limit would you set (i.e. how many entries before committing the transaction)?

Comment: @machinery I don't think that matters now, start with any number, e.g. once per second (20 inserts). Then tune it if you see performance problems, but do not attempt to optimize before seeing any performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how it is used, SQLite can be faster than direct filesystem I/O.
[35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html).

An extract (conclusion made) from the above :-

> So let your take-away be this: read/write latency for SQLite is
>   competitive with read/write latency of individual files on disk. Often
>   SQLite is faster. Sometimes SQLite is almost as fast. Either way, this
>   article disproves the common assumption that a relational database
>   must be slower than direct filesystem I/O.

Of course that is considering only raw data access and then blobs (which may or may not be more favourable). When indexes start being involved then basically you are adding additional tables which have to be updated. It would likely be a fair assumption that the readings would likely  be more than a single value and that they type of reading (what sensor made the reading) and when that reading was made would also be recorded values, so those extra values need to be considered as they could well be indexed (perhaps creating indexes when needed and then dropping them when done with could be beneficial).

As such it may well be that at some stage, if such values are indexed then the filesystem would be faster. However, that would very likely be at the expense of more complex and slower retrieval.

There are also system parameters for example sqlite [PRAGMA's (***page size*** linked)](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size) can be used to adjust some settings.

You would probably NOT want to include **AUTOINCREMENT** [What are the overheads of using AUTOINCREMENT for SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384919/what-are-the-overheads-of-using-autoincrement-for-sqlite-on-android)
.

In short you may well need to consider performance balancing/optimisation/experimentation over time.