# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column error even if column exists

Tags: sqlite

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but there is something wrong in my syntax and I can't figure out what. This is the method that adds my column:

Property declaration:

```
public static final String COLUMN_TS_MILIS = "ts_milis";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_PRODUCT + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_TS + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
        COLUMN_TS_MILIS + "timestamp integer default (cast(strftime('%s', 'now') as int))" +
        ");";
db.execSQL(query);
```

and this is the query that triggers the error:

```
Cursor totalCof = db.rawQuery("SELECT sum(" + COLUMN_PRICE + ")" + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE "  + COLUMN_TS_MILIS + "= date('now')", null);
```

What is wrong in my syntax? Many thanks for help!

Comment: Add a space here: `COLUMN_TS_MILIS + " timestamp......."` before `timestamp`, then uninstall the app and rerun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the column that is meant to be named as per **COLUMN_TS_MILIS**, have omitted a space between the column name and the column type and hence the column name is a concatenation of the column name and column type. So assuming COLUMN_TS_MILIS resolves to millis then the QL will be :-

```
`CREATE TABLE ......,millistimestamp integer default (cast(strftime('%s', 'now') as int))`
```

instead of

```
`CREATE TABLE ......,millis timestamp integer default (cast(strftime('%s', 'now') as int))`
```

Additionally you have specified two types, timestamp and also integer, this won't be an issue SQLIite wise but may lead to confusion.

As such you probably just want

```
`CREATE TABLE ......,millis integer default (cast(strftime('%s', 'now') as int))`
```

As such you probably want to use :-

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        COLUMN_PRODUCT + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_TS + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," +
        COLUMN_TS_MILIS + " INTEGER DEFAULT (cast(strftime('%s', 'now') as int))" +
        ");";
```

- Note **AUTOINCREMENT** has been removed as you almost certainly don't need it as it has [overheads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384919/what-are-the-overheads-of-using-autoincrement-for-sqlite-on-android/45384920#45384920).

To implement the change, you would have to drop the table, as it exists. The easiest way to do this is to either :-

1. delete the App's data or
2. uninstall the App

and then rerun the App (assuming that existing, if any, data can be lost).