# Does PRIMARY KEY constraint defined on table level guarantees AUTOINCREMENT and no values reuse?

Tags: sqlite

Consider the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    id INTEGER,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Does it guarantee that the `id` will be auto-incremented for every new insert AND that the values for deleted rows *will not* be reused?

I looked up in the documentation for Sqlite3, but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Missing rowids can be reused after the largest one in the table is a very large number indeed (or if the biggest one in the table is deleted), unless `AUTOINCREMENT` is used to change how a new rowid is calculated. See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for details.

Comment: Yes, I have read that document, but it didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` on it's own guarantees (requires) a unique integer value and will if no value is specifically assigned provide one until the highest value has reached the highest allowed value for a 64 bit signed integer (9223372036854775807) after which an unused value may be found and applied.

With `AUTOINCREMENT` there is a guarantee (if not circumvented) of always providing a higher value BUT if 9223372036854775807 is reached instead of allocating an unused number an SQLITE_FULL error will result. That is the only difference from the point of view of what number will be assigned.

Neither guarantees a monotonically increasing value.

Without AUTOINCREMENT the calculation/algorithm is equivalent to

- 1 + max(rowid) and if the value is greater than 9223372036854775807 an attempt is made to find an unused and therefore lower value.

  - I've not seen that anyone has come across the situation where a random unused value has not been assigned.

With AUTOINCREMENT the calculation/algorithim is

- the greater of 1 + max(rowid) or SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'the_table_name_the_rowid_is_being_assigned_to' and if the value is greater than 9223372036854775807 then SQLITE_FULL ERROR.
- noting that either way there is the possibility that the max rowid is for a row that eventually doesn't get inserted and therefore the potential for gaps.

The answer is perhaps best put as: it's best/recommended to use the **id** column solely for it's intended purpose, that of efficiently identifying a row and not as a means of handling other data requirements, and if done so, there there is no need for AUTOINCREMENT (which has [overheads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384919/what-are-the-overheads-of-using-autoincrement-for-sqlite-on-android/45384920#45384920))

## In short

> Does it guarantee that the id will be auto-incremented

**NO**

> values for deleted rows will not be reused?

**NO** for the given code

for :-

```
CREATE TABLE names (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT name TEXT NOT NULL)
```

again **NO** as if 9223372036854775807 is reached then an SQLITE_FULL error will result, otherwise **YES**.

---

So really AUTOINCREMENT is only really relevant (if the id used as expected/intended) when the 9223372036854775807'th row has been inserted.

Perhaps consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, somecolumn TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, somecolumn TEXT);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (9223372036854775807,'blah'); 
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (9223372036854775807,'blah');
INSERT INTO table1 (somecolumn) VALUES(1),(2),(3); 
SELECT * FROM table1;
INSERT INTO table2 (somecolumn) VALUES(1),(2),(3);
```

This creates the two similar tables, the only difference being the use of AUTOINCREMENT. Each has a row inserted with the highest allowable value for the **id** column.

An attempt is then made to insert 3 rows where the **id** will be assigned by SQLite.

3 rows are inserted into the table without AUTOINCREMENT but no rows are inserted when AUTOINCREMENT is used. as per :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, somecolumn TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.098s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, somecolumn TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.098s


INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (9223372036854775807,'blah')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.094s


INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (9223372036854775807,'blah')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.09s


INSERT INTO table1 (somecolumn) VALUES(1),(2),(3)
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.087s


SELECT * FROM table1
> OK
> Time: 0s


INSERT INTO table2 (somecolumn) VALUES(1),(2),(3)
> database or disk is full
> Time: 0s
```

The result of the SELECT for table1 (which may differ due to randomness) was :-

[image]